# flask db migrateができない

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

flask db migrateを実行すると以下のようにForeignkeyでエラーとなってしまっています。
コードのどこが違うのか、調べても調べても分からない状態です。

ご教示、アドバイスの程、お願い致します。

DBは、sqlite3を使っております。

```
# エラー内容

  File "C:\work\dev\Flask\DB\app.py", line 54, in BlogPost
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.Foreignkey('users.id'))
AttributeError: 'SQLAlchemy' object has no attribute 'Foreignkey'. Did you mean: 'ForeignKey'?
```

```py
# app.py

import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
 
app = Flask(__name__)
 
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'mysecretkey'
 
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///data.sqlite'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
 
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
Migrate(app, db)

# 外部キー制約有効化
from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine
from sqlalchemy import event

@event.listens_for(Engine, "connect")
def set_sqlite_pragma(dbapi_connection, connection_record):
    cursor = dbapi_connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON")
    cursor.close()

 
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
 
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    administrator = db.Column(db.String(1))
    # blog_postとのリレーション
    post = db.relationship('BlogPost', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')
 
    def __init__(self, email, username, password_hash, administrator):
        self.email = email
        self.username = username
        self.password_hash = password_hash
        self.administrator = administrator
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"UserName: {self.username}"


class BlogPost(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'blog_post'
 
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.Foreignkey('users.id'))
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now(timezone('Asia/Tokyo')))
    title = db.Column(db.String(140))
    text = db.Column(db.Text)
    summary = db.Column(db.String(140))
    featured_image = db.Column(db.String(140))
 
    def __init__(self, title, text, featured_image, user_id, summary):
        self.title = title
        self.text = text
        self.featured_image = featured_image
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.summary = summary
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"PostID: {self.id}, Title: {self.title}, Author: {self.author} \n"

 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

エラーメッセージに書いてありますよ

```
'SQLAlchemy' object has no attribute 'Foreignkey'. Did you mean: 'ForeignKey'?
```

Kが小文字になってます

Comment: 有難うございます。私も、再度、エラーを見て、気づきました。何回も見直してて、スペルミスは無いだろうとおもっていたのですが・・・

Comment: こういう時はエラーメッセージをテキストエディタにコピーしてみて、対象のテキストで検索をするといいですよ。
打ち間違いをしていたらその文字が検索に引っかからないので。